# Passing generic class type down class inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to declare a generic class with a 3 level inheritance
I'm having trouble getting the generic type through from the top of the inheritance tree to the generic.

So in this example the Type of Animal would be Dog.
How would this be achieved?

```
public class Animal<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{       
}

public class Quadruped<T> : Animal<T> where T
{
}

public class Dog : Quadruped<Dog>
{
}
```

At present I'm sure how to proceed, It's not valid

The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Animal'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour'. [Assembly-CSharp]

Comment: Well first you need the same (or more restrictive) constraint on the generic type for `Quadruped` as you have for `Animal`.  Then you need `Dog` to be a `MonoBehaviour` which will not be possible unless it's an interface.

Comment: `Dog` can inherit from `Animal` directly and everything is fine, but I want to introduce `Quadruped` inbetween.

Comment: I was just wondering, what is the advantage of the generic here?  Why wouldn't you just derive down the chain?  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work...

```
public class Animal<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{       
}

public class Quadruped<T> : Animal<T> where T : MonoBehaviour
{
}

public class Dog : Quadruped<Dog>
{
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this gives the following error in `Dog` :  `The type 'Quadruped<T>' conflicts with the imported type 'Quadruped<T>'` It also gives the following error in `Quadruped` : `The type or namespace name 'Animal<T>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You were first and after cleaning it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this class:

```
public class Quadruped<T> : Animal<T>
{

}
```

`Animal<T>` needs `T` to be a `MonoBehaviour`, but class `Quadruped<T>` is not applying any constraint to `T`, so as far as `Quadruped<T>` is concerned, `T` can be **any** type, which isn't valid, because `Animal<T>` explicitly expects a `MonoBehaviour`

You can solve this by applying the same constraint to `Quadruped<T>`:

```
public class Quadruped<T> : Animal<T> where T : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

Comment: This gives the following error in `Dog` :  `The type 'Quadruped<T>' conflicts with the imported type 'Quadruped<T>'` It also gives the following error in `Quadruped` : `The type or namespace name 'Animal<T>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Rob Try cleaning and rebuilding.